# How to set number of forms to appear based on user choice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I apologize if this question has been poorly worded. The reason I'm asking here is because I didn't know how to Google it properly.

Basically, I want the client to be able to specify a number (they could type the number in a textbox or there could be a series of numbers in a drop-down box or even radio buttons, i'm very flexible with this) that determines how many set of questions the form will display.

To put it into context to make it hopefully easier to understand:

-The form is for booking tickets

-If the client chose '1' at the start, it would mean one ticket so only one set of questions would be visible

-If the client chooses 2 then they want to book 2 tickets etc etc.

I'm looking for a method to implement this using html, css and/or jquery/javascript if needed.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: share us how much have you tried...

Comment: how do you want to submit those forms? together or separately?

Comment: I haven't really tried anything yet because I have no idea where to start!

Comment: @sgt I would like to submit the forms together if possible!

Comment: Create a hidden basic form, [clone it into a visible container when needed](http://api.jquery.com/clone/).

Comment: Here is the form in question: http://jsfiddle.net/sx79767t/2/

Comment: In the future you can use [Shadow DOM](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/) for this, but [support for that kinda sucks right now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=shadowdom).

Comment: Isn't it easier to just add a number text field before the different kind of tickets? Because if you order more then 1 ticket you probably want to see the same movie. So only the seating will change depending on the clients.

Comment: Yeah, I agree with @TeeDeJee, I dont see any personal detail fields in the form, so what difference does this makes. Add a "No. of seats" column and instead of showing multiple forms, add an available seat plan. Just a suggestion though.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sheepit plugin - [sheepit for form cloning](http://www.mdelrosso.com/sheepit/index.php?lng=en_GB&)

go through it. it can help you a lot.

Answer (score 0):

when user chooses number of seats, make a loop for each seat and repeat questions as needed. all in same form.

using php

```
for ($question = 0 ; $question < $_POST['SeatNumbers'] ; $question ++) { ... }
```

You then have to cycle thru the total number set of questions, I'm guessing you probably will use a SeatNumber input, in the above code you'll get a $SeatNumber0, $SeatNumber1 and so on.
Check to see if $SeatNumber exists, and process if it does.

Using JS, I define a max number for the options. and when user changes seat number, I show/hide each question with css "display:none"/"display:inline"

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle html content dynamically, you'll need to use Javascript.

You can hear event from your text field or your selector used for provide the number of ticket.

Try this with jQuery :

$('your_field_selector').on('change') or this $('your_field_selector').on('keyup')

If the event is triggered, you can get the value of the field with the jQuery method called "val()" :

$('your_field_selector').val()

Next insert your new html content in function of the value.

Here, There's also many jQuery method for do that like "append()","insertBefore()","insertAfter()"... etc

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the sort of thing your after.

The amount of sections within the form is generated by the number selected on the slider with each dynamically generated form element having a unique id depending on which ticket its for ie: ticket 3 has a name id of name3 ticket 14 would have a name id of name14 and so on to allow proper usage of each input through your server side post functionality.

here is a working jsfiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/fd78gkf3/](http://jsfiddle.net/Base/fd78gkf3/2/)

Excuse the generic form field names :)

```
<script>function showValue(newValue)
{
    document.getElementById("tAmount").value = newValue;
    document.getElementById("tAmountDisplay").innerHTML = newValue;
}
</script>
<script>
$(document).on("click", '#select', function() { 
    var formTimes = document.getElementById("tAmount").value;
    $('#forms').append('<form id="ticketForm">');
    for(var i = 1; i < formTimes; i++) {

        $('#forms').append(i);
        $('#forms').append('<div id="formPanel">');
        $('#forms').append('<label>Name</label><input id="name' + i +'" type="text"/>'+'<br/>');
        $('#forms').append('<label>Age</label><input id="age' + i +'"type="text"/>'+'<br/>');
        $('#forms').append('<label>Gender</label><input id="gender' + i +'" type="text"/>'+'<br/>');
        $('#forms').append('</div>');
    } 
    $('#forms').append('<input type="button"  id="submit" value="Submit"/>'+'</form>')
}); 
</script>
<span id="tAmountDisplay">0</span> Tickets
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="range" min="1" max="20" value="1" step="1" width="100px" oninput="showValue(this.value)" />
    <input type="hidden" id="tAmount"  name="tAmount" value=""/>
    <input type="button" id="select" value="Select" />
    <div id="forms">

    </div>
</form>
```